# VBA - custom number formats from arrays - error after certain array number

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, number-formatting

I am having trouble trying to figure out why my code is not working. Let me paste it first:

```
Dim n As Integer
Dim List_number As String

Dim arr_number(1 To 26) As Integer
    arr_number(1) = "1"
    arr_number(2) = "2"
    arr_number(3) = "3"
    arr_number(4) = "4"
    arr_number(5) = "5"
    arr_number(6) = "6"
    arr_number(7) = "7"
    arr_number(8) = "8"
    arr_number(9) = "9"
    arr_number(10) = "10"
    arr_number(11) = "11"
    arr_number(12) = "12"
    arr_number(13) = "13"
    arr_number(14) = "14"
    arr_number(15) = "15"
    arr_number(16) = "16"
    arr_number(17) = "17"
    arr_number(18) = "18"
    arr_number(19) = "19"
    arr_number(20) = "20"
    arr_number(21) = "21"
    arr_number(22) = "22"
    arr_number(23) = "23"
    arr_number(24) = "24"
    arr_number(25) = "25"
    arr_number(26) = "26"
    n = 1

List_number = "\" & arr_number(n) & "\._1@"

Dim myformat As String
Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Selection
        List_number = "\" & arr_number(n) & "\._1@"
        myformat = List_number
        cell.NumberFormat = myformat

        n = n + 1

    Next cell
```

What I am trying to achieve with this code is to create some kind of simple list in excel, changing the custom format from "cell.value" to "myformat.cell.value". Please see the screen below:

[image]

My code is adding number, dot and space before each cell value. It works great for the first 9 cells but I have no idea why it gives an error at 10th cell: "Run-time error '1004' Unable to set the NumberFormat property of Range Class".

Weird behavior is that when I enter letters into my array it works great, but with numbers, it does not :(

I have tried multiple things (for example trying to split my "10" value from array into two separate pieces like "1" & "0") but after a few hours of no success, I gave up.

I have two questions:
1) Does anyone know why this error is popping up and how can I bypass it to continue with my macro?
2) Is there any way to assign values to arrays without the need to type each line separately? Both for number and for custom characters, like letters or signs?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I have tried to delete some of the formats, but there are not that many of them... It cannot be the reason. The issue happens even if I try it on a completely "fresh" workbook.

Comment: Excel is telling us that **\10\._@** is not a valid format !

Comment: @ExcelHero It does not have to be with number formats, I just thought it would be wise to use them, as if the value of a cell (string) changes, the format remains. Do you think it would be better to use formula and store the formula result as a string in cell?

Comment: It depends. Do want the final results to appear in the exact same range as the original data? Or is it OK to use a formula from a new range and keep both the original unaltered data in the original range and have the results in the new range?

Comment: I want to have the new value exactly in the place of old value. If values are in range A1:A10, the new "listed" values should be in the same range... I do not understand why Excel do not let me put "10" from array into number format... I have tried to use format \1\0... instead of \10 but it does not work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It uses a different number format: `"1." @`

```
Sub Kowalski()
    Dim f
    f = [char(34)&row(1:999)&"."&char(34)&" @"]
    Selection.NumberFormat = f
End Sub
```

How this works:

`Dim f` creates a variant variable.

The next line uses Excel's Evaluate method denoted by the square brackets to create a 2d array of 999 strings that will serve as number formats. This line also assigns that array to `f`.

The last line assigns in one go the array of separate number formats to your current range selection on the worksheet.

The `f` array looks like this:

```
f(1,1) = "1." @
f(2,1) = "2." @
f(3,1) = "3." @
f(4,1) = "4." @
f(5,1) = "5." @
.
.
.
f(999,1) = "999." @
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I have marked your post as an answer. One more question - is there any quick or easy way to store many values in an array? For example, I would like to store 50 different letter combinations (strings) in an array. I want to assign them in a code - do I need to repeat "arr(1) = xxx" 50 times or is there any easier way to do this? Or if not easier, then looking "cleaner" in the code?

Comment: Yes, you could use a loop. Or simpler yet, is the way I stored 999 different strings in an array in my answer.